# A Problem Regarding Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $F$ be a field, unique $ a_0, a_1, ... ,a_n \in F $, and let $ b_0, b_1, ... ,b_n $ be some elements in $ F $ (not necessarily different).

A) Prove there exists a unique $ f \in\mathbb{F}[x] $, with $ deg f \le n $, and $ f(a_i) = b_i $ for all $ 0\le i\le n $.

B) Let $ F = \mathbb C $, and let $ b_i = \overline{a_i} $.
Prove there exists $ f \in\mathbb{R}[x] $ of some degree, such that $ f(a_i) = b_i $ for all $ i $.

Hint: consider the set $ A = {{a_i}}\cup{{\overline{a_i}}} $, and by using A), prove that $ f = \overline{f} $.

I've proven A), But not B). I tried to define a linear transformation, but since $ a_i $ might be equal to $ \overline{a_i} $, I'm unsure of what N-tuple I'd pick. Am I looking at this from the wrong direction?

Comment: There is a problem in the hint, as what you would want to prove is that $f=\tau\circ f\circ\tau$ where $\tau(z):=\overline{z}$. The identity $f=\overline{f}(=\tau\circ f)$ for a polynomial $f\in\mathbb{C}[x]$ implies $f=0$. And I don't see why it would be a problem if $a_i=\overline{a_i}$, in this case you assign to it the value $b_i=\overline{b_i}$ (part A works for any $a_1,\ldots,a_n$, not necessarily distinct, if you add the extra condition that $b_i=b_j$ whenever $a_i=a_j$).

Comment: @imtrying46 are you sure you're thinking of elements in the polynomial ring $\mathbb C[x]$?  My guess is you are thinking of polynomial functions from complex analysis, in which case the implication isn't $f=0$ per se but constant $f$ (and evidently real).  The mention of $f=\tau\circ f\circ\tau$ also looks like complex analysis; the notion of function composition $f\circ \tau$ doesn't register since $f$ is not a function but an element in $\mathbb C[x]$.

Comment: Yeah. The problem I'm having is that f should be in the Reals, I'm unsure how to approach that.

Comment: @user8675309 You’re right, of course if $f=\overline{f}$ then $f$ is constant real, not necessarily $0$. But I don’t get your problem about distinguishing polynomials from say holomorphic functions. If $R$ denotes the ring of holomorphic functions, then there is an injective ring homomorphism $\mathbb{C}[x]\to R$, assigning to a polynomial the associated function. So it makes perfect sense to regard polynomials as holomorphic functions, and use complex analysis on them. For example, the fact that every polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ has a root is typically proven by using complex analysis.

Comment: @imtrying46 The issue is that $f\in \mathbb C[x]$ which is a field with a single element "$x$" adjoined to it hence a polynomial ring; "x" is compatible w/ linear combinations w/ itself and elements in $\mathbb C$ but there is no additional element $\bar x$. You can do a homomorphism $\phi$ into the ring of entire functions if you like but $\phi\circ f\neq f$. Yet $\bar f \in \mathbb C[x]$ which is to say $\bar f$ is $f$ with all scalars $c_k \in \mathbb C$ conjugated, so the official hint is fine. Put differently: you are working in a different ring than the OP which causes discrepancies.

Comment: @user8675309 I see what you are saying, but in this case the notation $\overline{f}(=\tau\circ f\circ\tau)$ as the polynomial where all the coefficients are conjugated is somewhat misleading, at least to me. In the context of the question it’s implicit that one does see polynomials as functions here, justifying the notation $f(a_i)=b_i$. Seeing the notation $\overline{f}$ I immediately assumed that it must signify “view $f$ as a function and post-compose with conjugation”. That’s why I wrote the initial comment. I wasn’t claiming anywhere that $\tau\circ f\in\mathbb{C}[x]$.

Answer (score 1):

An explicit way to do (A) and (B) is via an Vandermonde matrix.  For (B), let $S:= \big\{a_1,\dots, a_n\big\}\cup\big\{\overline a_1,\dots, \overline a_n\big\}$ with $r:=\big \vert S\big \vert$ and consider the degree $r$ polynomial
$c_0 + c_1 x + \dots c_r  x^r = p(z) \in \mathbb C[x]$.
Examine the equation
$V\mathbf c = \mathbf b$ where the $r\times r$ Vandermonde matrix has the moment curve $[1, s, s^2, ..., s^{r-1}]$ for $s\in S$ on each row, each of which is unique, each row of $\mathbf b$ contains the value of $p$ when evaluated at $s$ (technically a substitution homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb C[x]\rightarrow \mathbb C$) and $\mathbf c$ has the coefficients of $p$ to be solved for.  $V$ is invertible since all rows are unique hence $\mathbf c$ is uniquely specified.  But for for some permuation matrix $P$
$\big(P V\big)\overline {\mathbf c} =\overline V\overline {\mathbf c} = \overline{\mathbf b}=P\mathbf b\implies V\overline {\mathbf c}=\mathbf b$
$\implies \big(\overline {\mathbf c}-\mathbf c\big)\in \ker V\implies \mathbf c\in \mathbb R^r$, i.e. the coefficients of $p$ are real since $V$ is injective

Answer (score 0):

Let $\# A=2n-m.$ That means $a_k=\overline{a_k}$ for $m$ values of $k.$ By (A) there is a unique polynomial $p(z)$ of degree $2n-m-1$ such that $p(a_i)=\overline{a_i}$ and $p(\overline{a_i})=a_i.$ Consider the polynomial $q(z)$ with the coefficients that are complex conjugate of the coefficients of $p(z),$ i.e. $q(z)=\overline{p(\overline{z})}.$ Then
$q(a_i)=\overline{a_i}$ and $q(\overline{a_i})=a_i$ for any $i.$ By the unicity we get $q(z)=p(z).$ Hence the coefficients of $p(z)$ are real numbers.